# Issues with Java in Linux

Tags: linux, java, elementary-os

Firstly, I would like to apologize as I'm not quite sure whether this question is suitable to be on this site or Stackoverflow. I chose U&L eventually because the traffic here is much lower compared to SO, and it makes my question stay longer on the main page.

I'm currently on Elementary OS 0.3 Freya. After installing it, one of the first few things I did was getting the Java using the commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer`

However, at that point, I wasn't quite sure what kind of Java(JVM,JRE,JDK) I was actually installing due to unclear understanding regarding those terms. Everything was fine until I started to use Android Studio. The installation went smoothly but I was [prompted an error on the start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411989/android-studio-unrecognized-vm-option-maxpermsize-256m/31414868#31414868) of the program itself. Having tried many ways but to no avail, I decided to reinstall my Java. This is the [method I used to uninstall Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java). To make sure that I've completely removed it, I run the command `java --version` to check. The result showed that I got the Java uninstalled but what exactly that sparked my curiosity was that I could still run my Android Studio, which is written in Java. And so I searched up and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547458/what-is-the-difference-between-jvm-jdk-jre-openjdk) to clear up my misconception and realize that I had installed JRE twice because the JDK, which includes JRE, was also downloaded before the installation of Android Studio took place.

So, here's my question:

1. When we execute the three lines I listed above to install Java, are we installing the JRE or the JDK?
2. Do we need to install JRE if we are also going to install JDK? (Since JDK includes JRE)
3. Is there any commands that can install JDK like those three lines?
4. Why can't the system detect the JRE in the JDK I downloaded from the official site when I run `java --version`?
5. What is the difference(s) between the program that is installed using terminal and those who is downloaded from the web?

Sorry for putting five questions in a single thread. And for reading my laughable experience. You probably are laughing at my stupidity now, but I still hope you can help out to clear my doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am only laughing at all those apologies. I recommend that you tidy the question a little. Then flag this comment as obsolete.

Comment: Java 9??? Java 9 hasn't even been released yet.

Comment: @richard Hi! Thanks for the input Richard! Any advice on tidying up my questions? And, well, I believe the way I convey my message in the public (including internet) is already a habit now. Can't really put myself in superiority. :)

Comment: @saiarcot895 Hi! Have a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a94MxHHzn1Q #06 is the Java installation.

Comment: I _really_ like how they say "install Oracle Java" and ignore OpenJDK, and that too, to install Java 9, which is scheduled to be released in a year.

Comment: @saiarcot895 But it still works. How is that possible to install before the release? Is it a preview?

Comment: @Caesium95: Yes, there are developer builds while the developers are working on Java 9, but note that there are (or should be) no applications that require Java 9, and that those developer builds might break at any moment.

Comment: In the arch linux wiki, although in elementary os it is based on ubuntu and does not use the pacman package manager; the exposed information is valid for linux general: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java

Answer (score 1):

Try with OpenJDK 7+ first (available in the repository).

If it is not working, try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

to install the official, Java **JDK**. You should not need the first command as you already done it, but that's for future reference.

The run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

in which you can specifically choose Java **JDK**. Then everything should work as expected.

---

PS: in my opinion, this question belongs here since it is OS specific and not related to programming *per se*. I mean, you could have replaced `Java` with any other program (well, that's the first time in a while that I've seen such a complicated installation on Linux, I guess this is Java's karma ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Can you elaborate more on the first sentence? Don't really get it. Anyway, I already had the JDK downloaded in my OS, but not installed I guess. Will the commands given overwrite it or affect anything internally? Lastly, I can't mark this as answer as you didn't give me the answers for all questions (kind of my fault actually). I hope you understand. :)

Comment: About the first sentence: openjdk is an alternative, open source, implementation of the Java language. It is in the repository, so you don't have to do anything special except an apt-get to install it and maybe the update alternatives to select it if you have multiple versions on your system.

Comment: Abput your question. First it is a bad practice to ask for more than one in a post (actually, this is considered ok if these are side questions that should be trivially answered once the OP knows the main answer). Here, your problem is with Java for Android Studio. You should have a working one now.

Comment: Downloading and installing from the original site was not meant to be for end users in Linux. That can happen, but not for things like Java. The problem is that these installers are a complete mess.

Comment: For the difference between JRE and JDK, do you own homework, this is trivial and answered everywhere on the internet! For Buddah's sake! The answer is given as the very first link in google, you don't even have to go on the actual site! It is in google's link description. Please plug in your brain. (That said, I have no grudge against you, but please understand that the remaining questions have already be answered a thousand of tiles)

Comment: Two last things. You need the jdk because you want to develop in java, the jre is only for executing it. With what I said in my answer and a very minimal amount of deduction, you can answer questions 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: If you install from the terminal, you get paquets that were crafted specifically for you system. It's a no brainer for the end user: everything is configured for him and things are put in the correct place to allow easy usage, automatic update and painless removal. If you install from the website, you have to do manual configuration, manual updates and removal as well as updates can be a real pain if the installer was not well coded.

Comment: @LTP Thanks for your time for the long reply. Unfortunately still, you failed to provide a clear answers to Q1,2,3 & 4. Why? I guess that's because you interpreted them incorrectly. Regarding the difference between the JRE and JDK, I've done my homework and even provided a link to what I read. What I want is just a simple Yes/No for Q1,2 & 3 and explanation for Q4 & 5. Anyway, I searched up the web and knew the answers for Q1,2 &3. Having you provided the answer for Q5, I would've to look up for the answer of Q4 elsewhere. Thanks for your effort though.